# Can operations with a time complexity mandated by the C++ standard dynamically allocate memory?

Tags: c++, standards, language-lawyer

The C++ standard doesn't mandate time complexity of memory allocation since that falls outside its domain (usually depends on however the OS behaves) but then does that mean anything with a specified complexity cannot dynamically allocate memory?

For example, most of the containers in the standard library are required to have a constant time complexity default constructor so any implementation that pre-emptively dynamically allocates memory would violate the standard. (Whether that specific behavior is desirable is beside the point -- it's just an example that's meant to sound somewhat reasonable.) Is that right?

Comment: What about [`std::stable_sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort), where it's O(N log²(N)) or O(N log(N)) depending on whether extra memory is available?

Comment: @chris That one *is* weird and almost seems to imply a constraint on time complexity of dynamic memory allocation but "if enough extra memory is available" could be interpreted as "if some chunk of statically allocated memory is sufficient".

Comment: It would have to ignore time complexity of memory allocation, since each container is templated on an allocator type, which could theoretically have any possible time complexity. I also disagree with your conclusion; as an example, `push_back` on a vector specifies amortized-constant time complexity, however, this may dynamically allocate (more) memory.

Comment: @chris - In the case of HP / Microsoft version of std::stable_sort, it allocates temp space for 1/2 the size of the data to be sorted, sorts both halves, copying as needed to end up with the first half in the temp space, the second half in the second half of the data, then merges the temp data with the second half back into the original data. There also seems to be some left over code that handled further recursion and splitting, but it looks to me like that code isn't being used anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard explicitly states what is included in "time complexity" it mandates:

`23.2.1[container.requirements.general]/2`

> All of the complexity requirements in this Clause are stated solely in terms of the number of operations on the contained objects. [ Example: the copy constructor of type `vector <vector<int> >` has linear complexity, even though the complexity of copying each contained `vector<int>` is itself linear. — end example ]

And for the functions outside that clause, complexity requirements are spelled out explicitly, e.g.

`25.4.3.1[lower.bound]/3` (that's `std::lower_bound`)

> Complexity: At most `log2(last - first) + O(1)` comparisons.

(note that only comparisons are counted: lower_bound can, and, for forward iterators, will perform a linear scan)

So yes, algorithms whose complexity is mandated by the standard can dynamically allocate memory, or do whatever else they feel like, as long as they satisfy the actual constraint.

Comment: I think the first quote isn't quite relevant but pointing out how to correctly "parse" the complexity requirements nails it.

Comment: @Praxeolitic The example in the first quote is relevant; even if each step of an algorithm does some arbitrary heavy lifting, it is counted as "1".. But yes, lower_bound gives the best demonstration of what it means to have a specified complexity.